# Erro ao gerar um APK assinado

Tags: android, android-studio

É assim, estou desenvolvendo um app onde quero usar o Google Maps, mas quando tento gerar o APK assinado recebo 2 (dois) erros:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

e

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED

O que pode ser? E qual é a possível solução?

Comment: Pelo que me parece o segundo erro é uma consequência do primeiro..  Seu projeto está muito grande, para isto deve-se adicionar o multidex (não recomendo pois seu aplicativo perde desempenho, tenta remover biblotecas não usadas).. Poderia mostrar o seu build.gradle, as dependências que seu projeto usa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai no seu arquivo build.gradle (dentro da pasta /app)

e no seu defaultConfig, adicione essa linha:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Vai ficar assim:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.package.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: +1 já aconteceu comigo e resolvi desta forma.